# Why do I get a text filter when the values are numbers?

Tags: excel

I have a table which is populated using VBA.
One colum gives me a text filter when the values are numbers.

[image]

The format is "Tal" (Number) for all cells.
The code that creates this column is this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("BE3").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3, Toyota!A:F,6,False), """")"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("BE3:BE" & lastrow1).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("BE3").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Essentially a vlookup that gets a number from a different sheet then to preserve the number it copy pastes values.

The value the vlookup fetches is a formula:

```
=TODAY() - INTEGER(D1)
```

Which returns the full days since the timestamp.
Yet again it's formatted as number.
[image]

So why would this cause the filter to be text filter? And can this be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Answer modified, try returning a 0. It will at least show you if it's the formula that's giving you text values. Based on your latest picture in your comment, most values are text.

= "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3, Toyota!A:F,6,False), 0)"

Comment: I can't see any difference on your formula from mine

Comment: Sorry, I put the detail of the suggested change in my explanation. I have now changed the formula as well for clarity.

Comment: That does not work. You end the string and start a new string directly after. It returns an error.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot about the fun of trying to get quotes in a String. In the dropdown in Excel, if you scroll to the bottom, are there any non-numbers?

Comment: Only empty values https://i.stack.imgur.com/unCWi.png . Since the table is a Excel table the size adjusts with the data so there is no values in the list that is not based on the formula

Comment: Presuming Tomma means Blank? If you temporarily add a column to your table and use the formula ISNUMBER are all the values True? Also, try the same thing against the data being returned by the VLOOKUP.

Comment: I'm home from work due to my daughter is ill. I will try it when I'm back at work.

Comment: Ok, wishing her a speedy recovery.

Comment: It returns as "expected" https://i.stack.imgur.com/iht9y.png . on the Toyota sheet, where the vlookup fetches it returns true on all values.

Comment: I can't replace it with a number, It must be nothing. I could use "N/A" but that is text for sure... The strange thing is that the column beside BD has this VBA code: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("BD3").Formula = "=IFERROR(TODAY()-VLOOKUP(D3,Instämplingar_lookup!A:D,3,FALSE),"""")"` which should result in a similar output. The only difference is that in BD I vlookup the date and make the calculation on the main sheet, in BE I vlookup the calculated value. But both columns are copy pasted as values to remove any formulas. BD has number filter BE has text filter.

Comment: But the data is the same, number or empty/blank/nothing. It seems like this is a bug.